# Pushing docker image through jenkins

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jenkins-pipeline

I'm pushing docker image through Jenkins pipeline, but I'm getting the following error:

> ERROR: Could not find credentials matching
>   gcr:["google-container-registry"]

I tried with:

```
gcr:["google-container-registry"]
gcr:[google-container-registry]
gcr:google-container-registry
google-container-registry
```

but none of them worked.

In the global credentials I have:

> NAME: google-container-registry
>
> KIND: Google Service Account from private key
>
> DESCRIPTION: A Google robot account for accessing Google APIs and
>   services.

Comment: Do you have an associated service account key with storage admin rights?

Comment: Is the Jenkins agent using that credentials file?

Comment: Yes, I have a service account key in json. I imported it in Jenking as a google service account.

Comment: check if you have https://plugins.jenkins.io/google-container-registry-auth/ plugin installed

Answer (score 4):

The proper syntax is the following (provided your gcr credentials id is 'google-container-registry'):

```
docker.withRegistry("https://gcr.io", "gcr:google-container-registry") {
  sh "docker push [your_image]"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to Jenkins → Manage Jenkins → Manage Plugins and install plugins:
Google Container Registry
Google OAuth Credentials
CloudBees Docker Build and Publish

Jenkins → Credentials → Global Credentials → Add Credentials, choose desired ‘Project Name’ and upload JSON file

[image]

Jenkinsfile:

```
 stage('Deploy Image') {
                steps{
                    script {
                        docker.withRegistry( 'https://gcr.io', "gcr:${ID}" ) {
                            dockerImage.push("$BUILD_NUMBER")
                            dockerImage.push('latest')
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

check if you have https://plugins.jenkins.io/google-container-registry-auth/ plugin installed.

After plugin installed use `gcr:credential-id` synthax

Example:

```
stage("docker build"){
    Img = docker.build(
        "gcpProjectId/imageName:imageTag",
        "-f Dockerfile ."
    )
}

stage("docker push") {
    docker.withRegistry('https://gcr.io', "gcr:credential-id") {
        Img.push("imageTag")
    }
}
```